# Spring boot security add custom filter in which chain?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I create a custom filter and use `addFilterBefore` add the filter in `configure` method.

```java
@Component
public class JsonWebTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter { ... }
```

`configure` method in `SecurityConfig` which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```java
@Autowired
private JsonWebTokenFilter jsonWebTokenFilter;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .addFilterBefore(jsonWebTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Above setting add the `jsonWebTokenFilter` in both `springSecurityChain`(internal, `additionFilter`) and `originalChain`, is it the correct way or I should add `FilterRegistrationBean` to avoid the filter add in `originalChain`?

I need to handler different authication filters with different urls. Without `FilterRegistrationBean`, all custom filters add in `originalChain`. I set the different configuration with `@Order` and separate the url path, but still the requests should pass all custom filters.

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class PrivateSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private PrivateTokenFilter privateTokenFilter;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                //...
                .antMatcher("/api/private/**")
                .addFilterBefore(privateTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class PublicSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private JsonWebTokenFilter jsonWebTokenFilter;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                //...
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .addFilterBefore(jsonWebTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

To solve the problem, I should add `FilterRegistrationBean` setting for both custom filters, is that the right way?

```
spring-boot version: 2.6.6
spring-security : 5.6.2
```

Comment: Adding the `FilterRegistrationBean` is the right way (or not make the filters a component if they don't require autowiring and just instantiate them yourself).